# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: opencv

Почему у меня выдаёт эту ошибку? Я когда установил `opencv-contrib-python` с помощью pip он мне присылает эту ошибку. Что не так?

Пожалуйста вот код:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

haystack_img = cv.imread('Images/TMNT 03.04.2022 23_30_41.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
needle_img = cv.imread('Images/TMNT 03.04.2022 23_30_41 (1).jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

haystack_len = len(haystack_img.shape)
print(haystack_len)
if haystack_len == 3:
    print(haystack_img.shape[-1])

needle_len = len(needle_img.shape)
print(needle_len)
if needle_len == 3:
    print(needle_img.shape[-1])

haystack_img.astype(np.float32)
needle_img.astype(np.float32)





result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

cv.imshow('Result', result)
cv.waitKey()
```

А вот текст ошибки:

```
    C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/iliya/PycharmProjects/OpenCV/OpenCV.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\OpenCV.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 175, in bootstrap
    if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module
    py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\iliya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\gapi\__init__.py", line 290, in <module>
    cv.gapi.wip.GStreamerPipeline = cv.gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Вот так?

```
import cv2; cv = cv2
import numpy as np

haystack_img = cv.imread('Images/TMNT 03.04.2022 23_30_41.png')
needle_img = cv.imread('Images/TMNT 03.04.2022 23_30_41 (1).jpg')

haystack_len = len(haystack_img.shape)
print(haystack_len)
if haystack_len == 3:
    print(haystack_img.shape[-1])

needle_len = len(needle_img.shape)
print(needle_len)
if needle_len == 3:
    print(needle_img.shape[-1])

haystack_img.astype(np.float32)
needle_img.astype(np.float32)





result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

cv.imshow('Result', result)
cv.waitKey()
```

Если так то всё равно появляется

Comment: Скорее всего у вас какой-то из файлов называется как файл из этой библиотеки

Comment: Ну и требования к вопросам не изменились: нужно приводить в вопросе код и полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Нужен полный текст ошибки вместе со всем стектрейсом и нужно имя вашего файла.

Comment: Попробуйте зменить `import cv2 as cv` на `import cv2; cv = cv2`. Ошибка уйдёт?

Comment: Она всё равно появляется

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72706073/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-gapi-wip-gs